# Crop Photo in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, android-camera-intent

What I am aiming for is to take images with an `intent` with the Android camera and then let the user crop the image. The problem is that I am looking to get a circular image (preferably a transparent background `.png`.

**Here is an example:**

[image]

I haven't found anything and I'm aware it can be hard to achieve, but I'm open to any alternative: use an existing application as an intent, change the circular shape for another easier to achieve, etc.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you see this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/12089127/1342638

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744119/crop-square-image-to-circle-programmitically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944275/crop-image-as-circle-in-android