# How to re-shape image into circular image in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

In android I designed one screen like this(Fig. 1 )

[image: Fig. 1] .

This profile photo I am getting from server. For time being I am trying it with a dummy image. Now I need to show the same image like this(Fig. 2 ) .

[image]

Is there any coding to implement this ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944275/crop-image-as-circle-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744119/crop-square-image-to-circle-programmitically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You can create a util method as `getRoundedCornerBitmap()` in your Util class as follows...

```
 public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = bitmap.getWidth();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
  }
```

For more details, you can follow [Rounded corner bitmaps on Android](http://ruibm.com/?p=184)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of previous answer I came up with this solution.Hope it help others:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class CircleImage extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.circle_layout);
        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.hair_four);
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);
        Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 100);
        img1.setImageBitmap(conv_bm);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

            int color = 0xff424242;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can code your own imageview and use that view in xml. Here is the code for that

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return; 
    }
    Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


            return output;
}

}
```

And then use that imagview in xml

```
<com.mypackage.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        ....
.../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code for circular ImageView programmatically. and put circular border around image as well if you want.

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);

     iv2.setImageBitmap(getCircularBitmap(icon));
```

\\

```
public Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    if (width <= height) {
        height = width;
    } else {
        width = height;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    int pixels = 850;
    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    // to Add Boorder
    float borderSizePx = 10.0f;
    float cornerSizePx = 850f;

    paint.setColor(0x33ffffff);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth((float) borderSizePx);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSizePx, cornerSizePx, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URL img_value = null;
try {
      img_value = new URL("paste your picture url here");

                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
                                Bitmap dstBmp;
                                try {
                                    mIcon1 = BitmapFactory
                                            .decodeStream(img_value
                                                    .openConnection()
                                                    .getInputStream());
                                    if (mIcon1.getWidth() >= mIcon1
                                            .getHeight()) {

                                        dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                                mIcon1,
                                                mIcon1.getWidth()
                                                        / 2
                                                        - mIcon1.getHeight()
                                                        / 2, 0, mIcon1
                                                        .getHeight(),
                                                mIcon1.getHeight());

                                    } else {

                                        dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                                mIcon1, 0,
                                                mIcon1.getHeight() / 2
                                                        - mIcon1.getWidth()
                                                        / 2,
                                                mIcon1.getWidth(),
                                                mIcon1.getWidth());
                                    }

                                    circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                            dstBmp.getWidth(),
                                            dstBmp.getHeight(),
                                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(
                                            dstBmp, TileMode.CLAMP,
                                            TileMode.CLAMP);
                                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                                    paint.setShader(shader);

                                    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                                    c.drawCircle(dstBmp.getWidth() / 2,
                                            dstBmp.getHeight() / 2,
                                            dstBmp.getWidth() / 2, paint);

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                profileImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                                profileImage.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```