# save pictures from surfaceview

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

it is possible to save pictures from surfaceview? I want a costum camera(smaller than screen) I want the preview and take pictures.
I try a lot of code but nothing work properly

[How to capture image from custom CameraView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391329/how-to-capture-image-from-custom-cameraview-in-android)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen/27824250#27824250

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and code by your link is correct in common case. But there is one more thing which you should check if you trying to convert data to specific format in callback:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1)
```

You can check picture format of Camera arg with [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPictureFormat%28%29):

```
public int getPictureFormat ()
```

This returns [ImageFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html) (like JPEG, NV21, YUV etc,) for camera in your device. You should use this value to format correctly byte data from onPictureTaken because BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length) method can work correctly only with JPEG or PNG data.

From Android Developer [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) documentation:

> Prior to KITKAT additional constraints apply: The image being decoded
>   (whether as a resource or as a stream) must be in jpeg or png format.
>   Only equal sized bitmaps are supported, with inSampleSize set to 1.
>   Additionally, the configuration of the reused bitmap will override the
>   setting of inPreferredConfig, if set.

Additionally I propose you to use TextureView instead of SurfaceView because in this case you can use simple way and get picture from TextureView by this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap%28%29):

```
public Bitmap getBitmap ()
```