# Android custom camera with circular border

Tags: android, camera, android-custom-view

I need a custom camera with circular border in my application for creating an avatar for user. Below I've attached photo with example in Flickr app. Unfortunately, I have no idea how can I do this. Help me, please[image: ![Camera in Flickr application]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKln7.jpg)

Comment: You need to create custom camera that will cover only the circular area Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392209/5907003