# How to Capture Frame currently running on Surface view?

Tags: android, image, screenshot, surfaceview, capture

I am trying to capture Frame which is currently getting displayed on Surface view and make Image of it. I sow almost all the solutions which I found on internet but no luck, **Image is Blank** ;(.

Any solution?

Regards,

Sachin

Comment: try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15392209/5275436

Comment: Thanks for instant reply.. But the scenario is like.. I am showing two surface views side by side and then trying to get screenshot of mobile(i.e. Activity) but it is showing blank in surface views.