# Circular video player using texture view in android

Tags: android, android-videoview, textureview, android-textureview

I have to create a circular video player using **textureview** in android. I don't have idea how to achieve this. Kindly help.

Comment: https://github.com/developer-anees/android-round-camera2video-preview this sample may help you

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to modify the Camera output as you record it, but this has nothing to do with TextureView. You can use a GLES fragment shader or apply a mask bitmap with GLES. Grafika ( github.com/google/grafika ) has some relevant code, but doesn't do what you're specifically asking for

Comment: I have to use the textureview to play a video in circular shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by providing **overlay** of `TextureView`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391329/how-to-capture-image-from-custom-cameraview-in-android) is sample how you can achieve!