# Clicking Custom Shape Photo in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I have built an activity where I have created an overlay on the camera interface..which looks like

[image]

But the problem is when I take photo with this custom looking camera it produces the normal square images..

So how can I have the picture of the only the region that is showing currently in the camera-screen (as shown in the picture a circular area)

Comment: you can capture normal image and after you that you crop it the way you want..

Comment: means -there is no way i can only concentrate on the region while clicking the picture?

Comment: check this out.. maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392209/5148289