# how can i make camera preview of circle shape in android?

Tags: java, android

i am making an android app where the camera preview part is circle so that it will only have to capture the face of the user and beside the circle part make other part black.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy7YE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That would imply making a custom camera yourself instead of using the default one.

Refer to this link for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392209/7528995

You could also use the normal camera instead, since making the user fit their head inside the circled preview would be a bit inconvenient. After capturing the photo you could simply put it into a **CircleImageView**.

To do this you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36613446/7528995