# I need help adding multiple images and text to my android button

Tags: android, image, button, background-image, android-studio

In android i am trying to add multiple images and multiple text in a single button here is a image link to what i am trying to do. "https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqRRu.jpg"i would love and appreciate any help on this i can get. Also to get the Circle images i was think of just using a drawable is the the best thing to do? I don't know how to make the image/profile picture to be a circle because when i add the drawable it adds it to the whole button not just the profile picture. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: wouldn't it be best to create listview for this ? + for circles follow this question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to set multiple images to a button. You can have a `RelativeLayout` with those images/texts, and set an `OnClickListener` to the `RelativeLayout` itself.

Comment: I dont understand how the on click listen will help with this? Can you explain a little more? Also did you see the image i posted?

Comment: Sure, the purpose of onclicklistener is replacing the button for a *clickable* RelativeLayout with the children you need (circle border, avatar image and texts)