# how do I show circular cut of image in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-imageview, shapes

I have a rectangular image that I want to appear circular in an ImageView? I tried the following to no avail.

I create a circular xml shape and apply it as the background of my ImageView. Then I add the png image as the `src` of the ImageView. But the image still appears rectangular in a circular view. When I try to scale the image in the view, it simply fills the view and forces the view to look rectangular. Of course I just want to effectively get a circular cross-section of the image, losing all four straight edges. I welcome any help.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/circular_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg_circle_shape"
        android:src="@drawable/img_1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#CCFFFFFF" />

    <size
        android:height="300dp"
        android:width="300dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: instead you can create a circular Bitmap image from a rectangle Bitmap...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android

Answer (score 0):

try it `splitTrack=-false` in `api21` or higher

for `SeekBar`, i test it work correctly.