# ImageView in circular through XML

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I'd Like to make any image from my `ImageView` to be circular with a border.

I searched but couldn't find any useful information (anything that I tried didn't work).

How can I achieve this through XML:
Create an `ImageView` with certain src and make it circular with a border?

Comment: How to change the src of ImageView in java code?

Comment: Good simple solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28096369/2162226 - all in Java, so you can apply this formatting dynamically to images at runtime

Comment: You have to put your ImageView inside the CardView because CardView only has a feature of accessing the corner radius attribute.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

You can make a simple circle with white border and transparent content with shape.

```
// res/drawable/circle.xml

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Then make a layerlist drawable and put it as background to your imageview.

```
// res/drawable/img.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</layer-list>
```

and put it as background to your imageview.

```
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img"/>
```

You'll have something like that.

[image]

Comment: And then I set that shape to the background of my imageview? I've tried that but didn't work. My image still rectangular :(

Comment: you have a rectangular image and you want clip around it like a circle shape?

Comment: yes, using XML, because using java code is very expensive to the mobile. With this code it only appears a circle behind my image, not the image itself being a circle. I presume is for the border, I want the image to me rounded in a circle within this one

Comment: But still something wrong. Besides the image has the circular border in front, it's not transparent outside the circle. I mean, the circle is there, however, the image corners are visible and transcends the circle area behind it

Comment: add another shape in to the layerlist, but this time it should be rectangle with borders, it will cover corners with white

Comment: in graphical layout it is showing rounded corners but, when i load images from network it is loading as rectangle only

Comment: which image loading lib do you use or how do you load images?

Comment: How can I define the size of layer list?

Comment: How to change the src of ImageView in java code if I adopt this way?

Comment: What if I want to use RemoteView (of AppWidget) ? Would it still be possible using this? Maybe even as 2 views (on on top of another) ?

Comment: Copying these xml's leads to some ugly view with white bars and totally malformed things and no visible image at all.

Comment: If I understand this solution correctly, it covers the unwanted portions of the image with a solid color. It does not removes the unwanted portions like a stencil would do. Is this correct?

Comment: why am I getting a line from the border to the center. (radius)?.. how can I delete it.. tried different settings but still there

Comment: @miatech that is a bug in the preview. It is not visible on the device

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work with Picasso images caught from an URL.

Answer (score 370):

This is the **simplest** way that I designed. Try this.

dependencies

- implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
- implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

  ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:elevation="12dp"
       android:id="@+id/view2"
      app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:innerRadius="0dp"
       android:shape="ring"
       android:thicknessRatio="1.9">
       <ImageView
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
       </ImageView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  ```

  If you are working on android versions above lollipop

  ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:elevation="12dp"
   android:id="@+id/view2"
   app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
   <ImageView
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  ```

**Adding Border to round ImageView - *LATEST VERSION***

Wrap it with another CardView slightly bigger than the inner one and set its background color to add a border to your round image. You can increase the size of the outer CardView to increase the thickness of the border.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  android:layout_width="155dp"
  android:layout_height="155dp"
  app:cardCornerRadius="250dp"
  app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="150dp"
      app:cardCornerRadius="250dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="150dp"
          android:src="@drawable/default_user"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Simple, and easy on memory usage. The libraries I have tried so far all give OOMExceptions when using the Custom views in RecyclerView items.

Comment: Best solution among others, only don't preview it during design.

Comment: Tried using this , looks like it does not work with Android below 5.0. Even though the image view is circular, the images are smaller with square shape, looks terrible. Any suggestion? 5.0 and above works good.

Comment: my image doesn't fit the CardView with this method

Comment: This makes the cardview rounded but the image is still square beneath

Comment: What's up with `android:innerRadius="0dp" android:shape="ring" android:thicknessRatio="1.9"`? Those are not CardView attributes, are they?

Comment: hi, Can we make this clickable and change the drawable image programmatically??

Comment: how do it without rounding the card?

Comment: I think it makes sense to set the scale type of the image view: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: mine doesn't have `shape` property.

Comment: This does not work. Different devices (screens) will have a deformed shape.

Comment: I've tried, but no luck. I'm not sure, but I think tiny images doesn't go well with this approach.

Comment: Thanks, Key here is Card radius must be half of the width and height to make a proper circle.

Comment: This is not working. Image is overlapping card and becomes a square.

Comment: I used your first solution (one card view and an image view in it). But because my views sizes are calculated dynamically I had to set radius dynamically too. As @B.shruti said my calculation is "parent / 2". Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Buggy answer. The image is overlapping CardView.

Comment: idk what's up with this approach using cardviews, but they look good on pixel phone and weird on samsung. be aware!

Answer (score 208):

With the **Material Components Library** Just use the **`ShapeableImageView`**.
Somethig like:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageViewRounded"
    app:strokeColor="@color/....."
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    ...
    />
```

with:

```
  <style name="roundedImageViewRounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.2.0`**.

---

With **jetpack compose** you can apply the `clip` Modifier using a `CircleShape`:

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.xxxx),
    contentDescription = "xxxx",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .border(2.dp, Color.Blue, CircleShape)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Finally someone like Google Material came up with a rounded corners imageVview solution that kills all the badly written third party libraries people still use. Also, I do not recommend using the transformation on Glide since if you use placeholders, Glide does not allow you to add the transfromations to the placeholder as  well, sadly. So this answer solves all issues and is easiest to use.

Comment: Works as it should and should be the accepted answer. Only thing i noticed is that the image has to be a perfect square (which wasn't my case since i had a constraint layout with a drawable matching the constraints). Nice work as always Gabriele!

Comment: Much needed library. Worked well.

Comment: For some reason a corner size of 50% made the image invisible for me. Changing it to 49% fixed it.

Comment: When taking screenshot programmatically, image become square with black corners

Comment: Using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` almost fix the problem for images that are not in perfect square

Comment: How can I increase it's radius so it is a bit bigger than the image it self?

Comment: Border is not perfectly round. it becomes flat on the sides. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 182):

I hope this will help you.

**1) ShapeableImageView**

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:strokeWidth="10dp"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circleImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


 Style add here: res/values/style.xml or res/values/themes.xml
<style name="circleImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

**Don't forget implementation: Gradle Scripts > build.gradle (Module: app) > dependencies**

```
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
```

For complete description please check here : [The Source here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView)

**2) CircleImageView**

[image]

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

**Don't forget implementation: Gradle Scripts > build.gradle (Module: app) > dependencies**

```
     implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
```

For complete description please check here : [The Source here.](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

**3) CircularImageView**

[image]

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:civ_border_color="#3f51b5"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
    app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"/>
```

**Don't forget implementation: Gradle Scripts > build.gradle (Module: app) > dependencies**

```
     implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.1'
```

For complete description please check here : [The Source here.](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView)

Comment: How to change the grey color part to white ?

Comment: There's been an update since this was posted. border_colour and border_width have been renamed. Check the github page for more info: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: Doesn't support scale type. :(

Comment: hi its working fine when setting with src but its behaviour is different when trying to set using java code

Comment: @Erum  You need to just put  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'  in gradle file don't need java code.

Comment: I get bugreport on some devices

Comment: It showing me an error when I am using Scale type. Is there any way to solve this problem? I need a scale type to fit the whole image in the circle.

Comment: Actually the third-party library is the best solution and it works with images caught from an URL with Picasso really well.

Comment: It works for me, thanks. When set image resource or image bitmap it is rounded too. I love the lib

Answer (score 74):

With the help of [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library and [RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.html) class it's easy to achieve. You may need to create circular placeholder image.

**Glide V4:**

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(imageView);
```

**Glide V3:**

```
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(imgUrl)
        .asBitmap()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imgProfilePicture) {
            @Override
            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(),
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, 50, 50, false));
                drawable.setCircular(true);
                imgProfilePicture.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        });
```

For **Picasso** [RoundedTransformation](https://gist.github.com/amardeshbd/06b491d4adb568b1b226a20d4953a180), this is a really great solution that gives an additional option of rounding image at either top or bottom edge.

Comment: Not sure what version of glide you are using for this example, but with v4.0.0 you can simply use their RequestOptions instead of RoundedBitmapDrawable:


`Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())
    .into(imageView)`

Comment: Don't you mean; Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl).apply(new RequestOptions().circleCrop()) .into(imageView) ?

Comment: With version 4.6.1 use `.apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())`

Comment: In Glide v.4 if `GlideApp` is configured in an application: `GlideApp.with(this).load(url).circleCrop().into(imageView);`.

Comment: I can't believe it worked so easily without headche

Comment: V4 works like charm

Answer (score 34):

The above methods don't seem to work if you're using the `src` attribute. What I did is to put two image views inside a frame layout one above another like this:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame"
             android:layout_width="40dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/pic"
               android:layout_width="40dp"
               android:layout_height="40dp"
               android:src="@drawable/my_picture" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/circle_crop"
               android:layout_width="40dp"
               android:layout_height="40dp"
               android:src="@drawable/circle_crop" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Simply put a circular_crop.png in your drawable folder which is in the shape of your image dimensions (a square in my case) with a white background and a transparent circle in the center. You can use this image if you have want a square imageview.

> [image: Round image]

Just download the picture above.

Comment: best solution! best performance. change the bitmap is memory problem

Comment: This sample image is white so yeah. But you can create your own image in any color or download this image and just change its color.

Comment: Can you please explain how do I change the color of the image to black? can it be done from inside Android Studio or do I need an external tool (one can see I am not familiar with image creation)

Comment: No not from inside Android Studio. You'll need something like Photoshop. This photo itself was also created with photoshop

Comment: You could just give the circle drawable a color filter: circleCrop.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)). This way you could have a single circle drawable of any color and reuse it anywhere in your app on any background. Just set a color filter with the appropriate color resource each time.

Answer (score 20):

The following is one of the simplest ways to do it, use the following code:

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'      // use this or use the latest compile version. In case u get bug.
}
```

**XML Code**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"             //  here u can adjust the width 
    android:layout_height="96dp"            //  here u can adjust the height 
    android:src="@drawable/profile"         //  here u can change the image 
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"              //  here u can adjust the border of the circle.  
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>      //  here u can adjust the border color
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

*Source:* [Circular ImageView GitHub Repository](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't support scale type. :(

Answer (score 15):

you don't need any third-party library.

you can use the `ShapeableImageView` in the material.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize">
     <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

**in layout**

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile"
     app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize"
/>
```

you can see this

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView

or this

https://medium.com/android-beginners/shapeableimageview-material-components-for-android-cac6edac2c0d

Comment: also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62929433/2445763) in case this solution doesn't work.

Comment: My friend, you forgot to put a very important attribute on the styles.xml file. It won't work without the parent="" as stated on the second link you shared: <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent" parent="">
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use AndroidX [ImageFilterView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/utils/widget/ImageFilterView).

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:roundPercent="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gallery" />
```

[image: ImageFilterView sample image]

Comment: I found this to be the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use CardView without any external Library

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/roundCardView"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: The easiest way to go....

Answer (score 6):

This will do the trick:

rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:bottom="-14dp" android:left="-14dp" android:right="-14dp" android:top="-14dp" />

</shape>
```

circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="oval"

    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="15dp"
        android:color="@color/verification_contact_background" />

</shape>
```

profile_image.xml ( The layerlist )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangle" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>

</layer-list>
```

Your layout

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/default_org"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image"/>
```

Comment: what is default_org ?

Comment: this can be any placeholder image

Comment: in this case, the edges of an image in rectangular dimension will cross the boundaries of the circle. How can I exactly position each image, in every dimension and form, inside of the circle?

Answer (score 6):

Posting this answer for future reference. You can use `ShapeableImageView` available in `com.google.android.material:material`.

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_launcher_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:maxWidth="50dp"
    android:maxHeight="50dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:shapeAppearance="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/imageViewRounded"
    app:strokeColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Add `imageViewRounded` style in your styles.xml

```
<style name="imageViewRounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">51%</item>
</style>
```

You can add material design dependency if not added.

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Design looks like

[image]

Comment: Great answer ! It works nicely

Answer (score 5):

Best Solution courtesy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MHoNU7ytaw
the width and height of the card view determine the size of the images it contains  set up is as follows:

1. Add Dependency to Gradle(Module)
2. Add the xml code to activity.xml or fragment.xml file

````
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="270dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      app:cardCornerRadius="150dp"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/trans"
      >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/resultImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/congrats"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    </ImageView>


  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>```
````

Answer (score 5):

### Update 2021: Using Glide v4 CircleCrop see https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html

```
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vinyl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

In Code

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3828241/pexels-photo-3828241.jpeg")
            .transform(CircleCrop())
            .into(rootView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.vinyl))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'd upvote but can't encourage indecency.

Answer (score 4):

I use shape = "oval" instead of the "ring" below. It has worked for me. To keep the image within bounds, I use `<padding>` and set `<adjustViewBounds>` to true in my `<ImageView>`. I have tried with images of size between 50 x 50 px upto 200x200 px .

Comment: You can add the following as well `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

Answer (score 3):

@Jyotman Singh, answer is very good (for solid backgrounds), so I would like to enhance it by sharing vector drawable that can be re-colored for your needs, also it is convenient since vector one-piece shape is well scalable.

This is the rectangle-circle shape (@drawable/shape_round_profile_pic):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="284"
    android:viewportHeight="284"
    android:width="284dp"
    android:height="284dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0 142L0 0l142 0 142 0 0 142 0 142 -142 0 -142 0zm165 137.34231c26.06742 -4.1212 52.67405 -17.543 72.66855 -36.65787 11.82805 -11.30768 20.55487 -22.85153 27.7633 -36.72531C290.23789 158.21592 285.62874 101.14121 253.48951 58.078079 217.58149 9.9651706 154.68849 -10.125717 98.348685 8.5190299 48.695824 24.95084 12.527764 67.047123 3.437787 118.98655 1.4806194 130.16966 1.511302 152.96723 3.4990422 164.5 12.168375 214.79902 47.646316 256.70775 96 273.76783c21.72002 7.66322 44.26673 9.48476 69 5.57448z"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff" /> // you can change frame color
</vector>
```

Usage is the same:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/YOUR_PICTURE" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_round_profile_pic"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: And how is this is supposed to work? You simply display a circle above the image, while what actually asked is, how to crop the image, so it will look like a circle.

Comment: Please see @Jyotman Singh's answer above. It was helpful for me, so I enhanced it a bit. To crop image you could use: `GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(profilePhotoUrl)
.circleCrop()`

Comment: Thank you for the circle-in-a-rectangle shape! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Material Design in your app then use this

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/black">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/circular_image"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/your_img" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method without using any library is using ImageFilterView and setting round percentage to the view will make the circle round

> app:roundPercent="1"

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/custom_button_1"
        app:roundPercent="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etName"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use these lines of code and you are done :

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-130dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/profilemain" />
```

[image]

Don't forget to import :

```
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
```

Add this library in build.gradle :

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

Comment: you must be missing something in java class

Answer (score 1):

I did it like that, I used my background color in my vector image

ic_bg_picture.xml

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
  <path
      android:pathData="M100.6,95.5c0,-0.4 -0.1,-0.7 0,-1.1c-0.2,-0.7 -0.2,-1.4 -0.1,-2.1c0,-0.1 0,-0.2 0,-0.3c-0.1,-0.6 -0.1,-1.2 0,-1.8c-1,-1.3 -0.3,-2.9 -0.3,-4.3c-0.1,-28.7 -0.1,-57.3 -0.1,-86C68,-0.1 35.9,-0.1 3.8,-0.2C0.7,-0.2 0,0.5 0,3.6c0.1,32.1 0.1,64.2 0.1,96.2c31,0 62,-0.1 92.9,0.1c3.6,0 6.3,-0.2 7.5,-3.2C100.5,96.4 100.5,95.9 100.6,95.5zM46.3,95.2C26.4,94 2,74.4 3.8,46.8C5.1,27.2 24.4,2.7 52.6,4.6c20.2,1.4 43,21.3 41.5,45.1C96.1,72.4 73,96.8 46.3,95.2z"
      android:fillColor="#6200EE"/>
</vector>
```

in my case I created a vector and changed the android:fillColor="#6200EE"

by the color of my background

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/container_profile_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bg_picture"/>
```

[image: example]
[image: example 2]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class RoundedImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    private int borderWidth = 4;
    private int viewWidth;
    private int viewHeight;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBorder;
    private BitmapShader shader;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup()
    {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);

        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)
    {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)
    {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void loadBitmap()
    {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

        if (bitmapDrawable != null)
            image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        loadBitmap();

        if (image != null)
        {
            shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter - 4.0f, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
        viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Measure the text
            result = viewWidth;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            result = viewHeight;
        }

        return (result + 2);
     }
 }
```

and use this ImageView in layout like:

```
<com.app.Demo.RoundedImageView
     android:id="@+id/iv_profileImage"
     android:layout_width="70dp"
     android:layout_height="70dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

This Class is Custom Circular Imageview with shadow, Stroke,saturation and using this Custom Circular ImageView you can make your image in Circular Shape with Radius. Guys for Circular Shadow ImageView No need Github this class is enough.

Adding CircularImageView to your layout

```
CircularImageView c=new CircularImageView(this,screen width,screen height,Bitmap myimage);
yourLayout.addView(c);**


public class CircularImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView  
{
    private final Context context;
    private final int width, height;
    private final Paint paint;
    private final Paint paintBorder,imagePaint;
    private final Bitmap bitmap2;
    private final Paint paint3;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private BitmapShader shader;
    private float radius = 4.0f;
    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 8.0f;
    private float stroke;
    private float strokeWidth = 0.0f;
    private Bitmap bitmap3;
    private int corner_radius=50;


    public CircularImageView(Context context, int width, int height, Bitmap bitmap)     {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

   //here "bitmap" is the square shape(width* width) scaled bitmap ..

        this.bitmap = bitmap;


        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);


        paint3=new Paint();
        paint3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint3.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint3.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        imagePaint= new Paint();

        paintBorder.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);


        this.bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (bitmap.getWidth() - 40), (bitmap.getHeight() - 40), true);


        imagePaint.setAntiAlias(true);




        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Shader b;
         if (bitmap3 != null)
            b = new BitmapShader(bitmap3, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
         else
            b = new BitmapShader(bitmap2, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        imagePaint.setShader(b);
        canvas.drawBitmap(maskedBitmap(), 20, 20, null);
    }

    private Bitmap maskedBitmap()
    {
        Bitmap l1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(l1);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(radius, x, y, Color.parseColor("#454645"));
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        final RectF rect = new RectF();
        rect.set(20, 20, bitmap2.getWidth(), bitmap2.getHeight());

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, corner_radius, corner_radius, paintBorder);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, corner_radius, corner_radius, imagePaint);

        if (strokeWidth!=0.0f)
        {
            paint3.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, corner_radius, corner_radius, paint3);
        }

         paint.setXfermode(null);
        return l1;
    }




     // use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 250"  here corner radius will change 

    public void setCornerRadius(int corner_radius)
    {
        this.corner_radius = corner_radius;
        invalidate();
    }



    -------->use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 10.0f"  here shadow radius will change 

    public void setShadow(float radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
        invalidate();
    }

   // use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 10.0f"  here stroke size  will change 

    public void setStroke(float stroke)
    {
        this.strokeWidth = stroke;
        invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap updateSat(Bitmap src, float settingSat)
    {

        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmapResult =
                Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvasResult = new Canvas(bitmapResult);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix.setSaturation(settingSat);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
        paint.setColorFilter(filter);
        canvasResult.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, paint);

        return bitmapResult;
    }




  // use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 2.0f"  here saturation  will change 

    public void setSaturation(float sat)
    {
        System.out.println("qqqqqqqqqq            "+sat);
        bitmap3=updateSat(bitmap2, sat);

        invalidate();
    } 


}






        // Seekbar to change radius

                  radius_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            text_radius.setText(""+progress);
                            circularImageView.setCornerRadius(progress);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });


     // Seekbar to change shadow

                    shadow_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            float f= 4+progress/10.0f;
                            text_shadow.setText(""+progress);
                            circularImageView.setShadow(f);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });


           // Seekbar to change saturation

                    saturation_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            int progressSat = saturation_seekbar.getProgress();
                            float sat = (float) ((progressSat*4 / 100.0f)-1.0f);
                            circularImageView.setSaturation(sat);

                            text_saturation.setText(""+progressSat);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });


    // Seekbar to change stroke

                    stroke_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            if (progress==0)
                            {
                                float f=(progress*10.0f/100.0f);
                                circularImageView.setStroke(f);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                float f=(progress*10.0f/100.0f);
                                circularImageView.setStroke(f);
                            }

                            text_stroke.setText(""+progress);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });




             //radius seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="50"
                android:max="250"
                android:id="@+id/radius_seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





          //saturation seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="50"
                android:max="100"
                android:id="@+id/saturation_seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





    //shadow seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="0"
                android:max="100"
                android:id="@+id/shadow_seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




         //stroke seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="0"
                android:max="100"
                android:id="@+id/stroke _seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use what Google provides via the support library RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory class ([**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory) and [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable)), instead of using a third party library :

Gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val originalDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.avatar_1)!!
        val bitmap = convertDrawableToBitmap(originalDrawable)
        val drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, bitmap)
        drawable.setAntiAlias(true)
        drawable.cornerRadius = Math.max(bitmap.width, bitmap.height) / 2.0f
        avatarImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun convertDrawableToBitmap(drawable: Drawable): Bitmap {
            if (drawable is BitmapDrawable)
                return drawable.bitmap
            // We ask for the bounds if they have been set as they would be most
            // correct, then we check we are  > 0
            val bounds = drawable.bounds
            val width = if (!bounds.isEmpty) bounds.width() else drawable.intrinsicWidth
            val height = if (!bounds.isEmpty) bounds.height() else drawable.intrinsicHeight
            // Now we check we are > 0
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(if (width <= 0) 1 else width, if (height <= 0) 1 else height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            drawable.draw(canvas)
            return bitmap
        }
    }
}
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatarImageView" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**res/drawable/avatar_1.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:width="128dp" android:height="128dp"
        android:viewportHeight="128.0" android:viewportWidth="128.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF8A80" android:pathData="M0 0h128v128h-128z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFE0B2"
        android:pathData="M36.3 94.8c6.4 7.3 16.2 12.1 27.3 12.4 10.7,-.3 20.3,-4.7 26.7,-11.6l.2.1c-17,-13.3,-12.9,-23.4,-8.5,-28.6 1.3,-1.2 2.8,-2.5 4.4,-3.9l13.1,-11c1.5,-1.2 2.6,-3 2.9,-5.1.6,-4.4,-2.5,-8.4,-6.9,-9.1,-1.5,-.2,-3 0,-4.3.6,-.3,-1.3,-.4,-2.7,-1.6,-3.5,-1.4,-.9,-2.8,-1.7,-4.2,-2.5,-7.1,-3.9,-14.9,-6.6,-23,-7.9,-5.4,-.9,-11,-1.2,-16.1.7,-3.3 1.2,-6.1 3.2,-8.7 5.6,-1.3 1.2,-2.5 2.4,-3.7 3.7l-1.8 1.9c-.3.3,-.5.6,-.8.8,-.1.1,-.2 0,-.4.2.1.2.1.5.1.6,-1,-.3,-2.1,-.4,-3.2,-.2,-4.4.6,-7.5 4.7,-6.9 9.1.3 2.1 1.3 3.8 2.8 5.1l11 9.3c1.8 1.5 3.3 3.8 4.6 5.7 1.5 2.3 2.8 4.9 3.5 7.6 1.7 6.8,-.8 13.4,-5.4 18.4,-.5.6,-1.1 1,-1.4 1.7,-.2.6,-.4 1.3,-.6 2,-.4 1.5,-.5 3.1,-.3 4.6.4 3.1 1.8 6.1 4.1 8.2 3.3 3 8 4 12.4 4.5 5.2.6 10.5.7 15.7.2 4.5,-.4 9.1,-1.2 13,-3.4 5.6,-3.1 9.6,-8.9 10.5,-15.2m-14.4,-49.8c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9,-.7 1.6,-1.6 1.6,-.9 0,-1.6,-.7,-1.6,-1.6,-.1,-.9.7,-1.6 1.6,-1.6zm-25.7 0c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9,-.7 1.6,-1.6 1.6,-.9 0,-1.6,-.7,-1.6,-1.6,-.1,-.9.7,-1.6 1.6,-1.6z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E0F7FA"
        android:pathData="M105.3 106.1c-.9,-1.3,-1.3,-1.9,-1.3,-1.9l-.2,-.3c-.6,-.9,-1.2,-1.7,-1.9,-2.4,-3.2,-3.5,-7.3,-5.4,-11.4,-5.7 0 0 .1 0 .1.1l-.2,-.1c-6.4 6.9,-16 11.3,-26.7 11.6,-11.2,-.3,-21.1,-5.1,-27.5,-12.6,-.1.2,-.2.4,-.2.5,-3.1.9,-6 2.7,-8.4 5.4l-.2.2s-.5.6,-1.5 1.7c-.9 1.1,-2.2 2.6,-3.7 4.5,-3.1 3.9,-7.2 9.5,-11.7 16.6,-.9 1.4,-1.7 2.8,-2.6 4.3h109.6c-3.4,-7.1,-6.5,-12.8,-8.9,-16.9,-1.5,-2.2,-2.6,-3.8,-3.3,-5z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#444" android:pathData="M76.3,47.5 m-2.0, 0 a 2.0,2.0 0 1,1 4.0,0 a2.0,2.0 0 1,1 -4.0,0"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#444" android:pathData="M50.7,47.6 m-2.0, 0 a 2.0,2.0 0 1,1 4.0,0 a2.0,2.0 0 1,1 -4.0,0"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#444"
        android:pathData="M48.1 27.4c4.5 5.9 15.5 12.1 42.4 8.4,-2.2,-6.9,-6.8,-12.6,-12.6,-16.4 17.2 1.5 14.1,-9.4 14.1,-9.4,-1.4 5.5,-11.1 4.4,-11.1 4.4h-18.8c-1.7,-.1,-3.4 0,-5.2.3,-12.8 1.8,-22.6 11.1,-25.7 22.9 10.6,-1.9 15.3,-7.6 16.9,-10.2z"/>
</vector>
```

The result:

[image]

And, suppose you want to add a border on top of it, you can use this for example:

**stroke_drawable.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

And add `android:foreground="@drawable/stroke_drawable"` to the ImageView in the layout XML file, and you get this :

[image]

I'm not sure how to add shadow (that will work on older Android versions), though. Using [**FloatingActionButton**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton) (from the [**"com.google.android.material:material" dependency**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor)), I failed to make the bitmap fill the FAB itself. Using it instead could be even better if it worked.

---

EDIT: if you wish to add shadow of elevation (available from API 21), you can change a bit what I wrote:

**Inside the layout XML file:**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView android:padding="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/avatarImageView" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:elevation="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/stroke_drawable" tools:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar_1"/>
```

**CircularShadowViewOutlineProvider.kt**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class CircularShadowViewOutlineProvider : ViewOutlineProvider() {
    override fun getOutline(view: View, outline: Outline) {
        val size = Math.max(view.width, view.height)
        outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, size, size, size / 2f)
    }
}
```

**In code:**

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        avatarImageView.outlineProvider = CircularShadowViewOutlineProvider()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomImageview then simply override its `onDraw()` method follows:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float radius = this.getHeight()/2;
    Path path = new Path();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

In case you want the code for the custom widget as well:-

> **CircularImageView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

    private Drawable image;

    public CircularImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(null, 0);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        float radius = this.getHeight()/2;
        Path path = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray a = Utils.CONTEXT.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircularImageView, 0, 0);
        try {
            image = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CircularImageView_src);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        this.setImageDrawable(image);
    }
}
```

Also, add the following code to your **res/attrs.xml** to create the required attribute:-

```
<declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
        <attr name="src" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: This will work when the imageview doesn't have a background. What to do then?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution.
Create a new Image asset by right clicking your package name and selecting New->Image asset.
Enter name (any name) and path (location of image in your system).
Then click Next and Finish.
If you enter name of image as 'img', a round image with the name 'img_round' is created automatically in mipmap folder.

Then, do this :

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/img_round"/>
```

Your preview may still show a rectangular image. But if you run the app on your device, it will be round.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to set edit icon on to circle imageview than put this below code.

 <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_upload" />

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_camera"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                    android:src="@drawable/edit"/>
            </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you'd rather cut the image to display in circular,  here you go

```
public static Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output;

        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        float r = 0;

        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        } else {
            r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use `clipToOutline` property of an `ImageView`.

Here is an example layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Simple view to draw borders for an image,
         borders will be rounded because of the oval-shaped background. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_border"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_border"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- Image itself: fits the border view, 
         a margin serves as a border width;
         the key point here - is a background shape which will clip the view to its forms. -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/v_border"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/v_border"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/v_border"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/v_border" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here are our `shape_border` drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FF00FF" />
</shape>
```

And `shape_oval` drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" />
```

The only thing you should do in the code - is to enable `clipToOutline` property:

```
binding.ivImage.clipToOutline = true
```

And of course you can avoid even this line of the code with some [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter).

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively old question, but you can just make a circle border in the drawable folder (let's assume the xml file will be called `circle_border`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- If you want a padding -->
    <padding android:top="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />

    <!-- If you want the circle border to have a color -->
    <strong android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

Then you can use it as the background of the `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/circle_border"
    <!-- other attributes here -->
/>
```

Comment: This draws a circle behind the image, but doesn't cut it out to be circular.

Answer (score -1):

just use this simple code:
First add dependency :

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

then add in xml layout the following code:-

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:id="@+id/Imgshaligram"
                                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/shaligram"
                                        app:civ_border_color="#d1b1b1"

                                        android:foregroundGravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

also, these two libraries can help you.

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

implement below code:

```
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
```

**Simple Usage:**

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_border_color="#333333"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
        app:riv_oval="true" />
```

https://github.com/chirag-kachhadiya/RoundedImageView

**Simple Usage:**

implement below code:

```
implementation 'com.github.chirag-kachhadiya:RoundedImageView:1.0'



 <com.infinityandroid.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/the_hundred"
                app:corner_radius="10" />
```