# Circular ImageView in Android using XML

Tags: android

I want to make an ImageView circular. I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml) but this solution won't work for an image which is fetched from a server. I would like a solution using XML only since I prefer not to use any other alternative.

Comment: use this   https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Comment: Why it will not work for the extracted image from the server? oo

Comment: It's a good alternative, definitely. But unfortunately I'm not allowed to use external libraries.

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/10/android-custom-shape-imageview-rounded.html  this is coustom shaps

Comment: @user2413972: It is so because the solution fetches an image inside the layer-list from the drawable folder. I'd be grateful if you give me a workaround for this.

Comment: Why you can not manually set drawable?

Comment: @user2413972 I precisely tried that but couldn't get it to work. I'd request you to give me a few lines of code so that I can get the idea. I've never tried this before.

Comment: Naveen Tamrakar gave you perfect solution. Use it.

Comment: @user2413972 His solution is absolutely great, no doubt about it, but as I said earlier, I'm not allowed to use external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use library at all. Just a custom ImageView class.

```
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.res.TypedArray;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Shader;
 import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 /**
 * The Class CircularImageView.
 */
 public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

 /** The canvas size. */
 private float canvasSize, borderWidth;

/** The image. */
private Bitmap image;

/** The paint. */
private Paint paint;

/** The paint border. */
private Paint paintBorder;

/**
 * Instantiates a new circular image view.
 *
 * @param context
 *            the context
 */
public CircularImageView(final Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new circular image view.
 *
 * @param context
 *            the context
 * @param attrs
 *            the attrs
 */
public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.circularImageViewStyle);
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new circular image view.
 *
 * @param context
 *            the context
 * @param attrs
 *            the attrs
 * @param defStyle
 *            the def style
 */
public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintBorder = new Paint();
    paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);

    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.CircularImageView, defStyle, 0);
    if (attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border, true)) {
        setBorderWidth(attributes.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_width, 0));
        setBorderColor(attributes.getColor(
                R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_color, Color.WHITE));
    }

}

/**
 * Sets the border width.
 *
 * @param borderWidth
 *            the new border width
 */
public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
    this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    this.requestLayout();
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Sets the border color.
 *
 * @param borderColor
 *            the new border color
 */
public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
    if (paintBorder != null)
        paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Adds the shadow.
 */
public void addShadow() {
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
    paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.widget.ImageView#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
 */
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
    if (image != null) {
        canvasSize = canvas.getWidth();
        if (canvas.getHeight() < canvasSize)
            canvasSize = canvas.getHeight();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                image, (int) canvasSize, (int) canvasSize, false),
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);

        float circleCenter = (canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2;
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                + borderWidth, ((canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2)
                + borderWidth - 4, paintBorder);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                + borderWidth, ((canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2) - 4,
                paint);
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.widget.ImageView#onMeasure(int, int)
 */
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

/**
 * Measure width.
 *
 * @param measureSpec
 *            the measure spec
 * @return the int
 */
private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        result = specSize;
    } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        result = (int) canvasSize;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Measure height.
 *
 * @param measureSpecHeight
 *            the measure spec height
 * @return the int
 */
private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);
    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        result = specSize;
    } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        result = (int) canvasSize;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Drawable to bitmap.
 *
 * @param drawable
 *            the drawable
 * @return the bitmap
 */
public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

```
 and in attrs.xml
   <declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
    <attr name="border" format="boolean"></attr>
    <attr name="border_width" format="dimension"></attr>
    <attr name="border_color" format="color"></attr>
    <attr name="shadow" format="boolean"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="Theme">
    <attr name="circularImageViewStyle" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>

Thatsolve :)

in xml
 <package.views.CircularImageView
 android:id="@+id/img_pic"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap-content"
 android:src="@drawable/user_profile_image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have one for you. No third party dependency needed.
Change *src* in the ImageView as *background*
and *background* as *src* as follows
**image_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:width="60dp"
android:height="60dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
</item>
<item android:width="60dp"
android:height="60dp">
<shape android:shape="oval">
<stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="10dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**in your layout xml**

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:src="@drawable/image"
android:background="@drawable/picture"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you only want to use XML to do it the answer is : you can't.

What you need to do is to create your image view like in the [ImageView in circular through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml) solution you point out and programmatically set the background of the ImageView after you retrived it from the server.

In your activity :

```
// Retrieve the ImageView element you added to this activity
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);

// fetch your image form the server
Drawable d = //...

// Finally set the drawable to the image view.
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

This snippet will only change the background of your image view. It won't change its shape.