# Draw color bars vertically - android

Tags: android

I am trying to draw something like this:

[image: Color bar]

Whereas the bars number is dynamic, and it must be circular

I tried to put views inside LinearLayout oriented horizontally with weight sum = number of views (or number of color bars inside the circle)

and i put weight=1 for every view. then add the views to LinearLayout.

The problem is it is not circular.

How can I draw something like this to be circular as well?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33053086/4440874) answer. Just replace the second ImageView with a LinearLayout.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh The corners wont be transparent in that answer, He puts image above the image only. sounds good trick but not what im trying to find out.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use this Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHqsP.png as avatar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/circular_frame"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/circular_frame"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/circular_frame"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/circular_frame">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#aa00aa"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#aaaa00"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000aa"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#aa0000"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00aaaa"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/circular_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/avatar">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The corners wont be transparent here, will they? I want them to be transparent

Comment: @MBH what do you mean by transparent corner?

Comment: as it is rectangular, then i will put the image you suggested above it, the parts that will be covered will be ***white***, and what behind them wont be seen. Can i make them to be seen ?

Comment: No, That will be of the image colour you can use the image of any colour which is transparent form inside.

Comment: for making rounded corner image  you can use this   [link](https://github.com/manishsri01/AndroidCustomImageView)