# Failed to create a circular imageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I am using third party library (dependency) to make a circular `ImageView` in login page but I am not able to make it i.e. `ImageView` is not circular.

This is what I have tried.

**activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/violetred"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/profile"
        app:border_color="@color/white"
        app:border_width="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="325dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Create account"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: How do you set the image for the CircleImageView?

Comment: @Jj I follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36613446/2987882)

Comment: did you try the following? android:src="@drawable/image"

Comment: Does @mipmap/profile show in a normal ImageView?

Comment: @KuldeepYadav yes, the imageView still in square shape

Comment: @Jj Yes........

Comment: It seems all okay. Check with this README if you are doing all right. https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: I think the preview layout is a square, but when you run on the app, it's a circle

Comment: @cricket_007 It's still a square even I run it on app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not on my computer now, but i have one circle imageview working, but i think is from support.design library, you should check that. When i have my computer i can give you a better answer

UPDATE:

on your build.gradle add this to dependecies

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

And then, on your xml:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
way better solution is to use Picasso library

```
 Picasso.with(this)
.load(R.mipmap.profile)
.transform(new CropCircleTransformation() )
.into(ImageView);
```

Don't forget to add the library in gradle file

Comment: Btw this is not my library i just found some time ago, its the work of this guy https://github.com/hdodenhof

Comment: Since my answer was from some days ago i forgot that you are using the same library, but this is working for me, maybe you are missing the dependecies code

Comment: Not sure what's the problem is..I still can't get a circular image :(

Comment: Man, i think its because you are setting your image as background of the circular img, try to use it as source like me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is namespace collision

Try this

```
    app:civ_border_width="3dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
```

Instead of this

```
    app:border_color="@color/white"
    app:border_width="3dp"
```