# How to code a sort of layout in XML where a circular ImageView is aligned on top of a CardView as shown in the picture below?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I want to develop below shown sort of layout for my app.

[image]

I basically want to know how to align this circular `ImageView` on a `CardView` as shown above.

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: @USKMobility I know how to make CircleImageView. This is not what I want to know. I want to how to make a layout similar to shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be done through both image view and cardview put in relative layout.
Use com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView for Rounded image view.
Use something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="define it"
            android:marginTop="70dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"/>
        <com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/photo1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp"
            android:marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="16dip"
            app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="0dip"
            app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="48dip"
            app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="16dip"
            app:sriv_border_width="2dip"
            app:sriv_border_color="#008fea"
            app:sriv_oval="true" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want to know how to draw a circleimageview. Please see the edited question

Comment: Yes i given u answer of that too just replace 
    com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview with your circular image code and it will draw some thing like that

See i have given height of circle image 100dp and margin top of 20 dp in relative layout and card view margin top is 70 dp so it will make circular image 50dp above cardview so give  card view top padding of 60dp and do everythig u wanna do  in card view

Comment: Bro, the imageview is getting under cardview. How to bring it above the cardview?

Comment: can you please tell me how to bring it above the cardview?

Comment: Right cardview code 1st and than round image view this will bring it to top of card view

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways if you don',t want to use any third party library:
1st>You can use

```
<android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
android:layout_width=""
android:layout_height="" />
```

Get inside CircleImageView class to find what has been done.

2nd> We can Use layerList
you can find details here:
[ImageView in circular through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml)

now put imageview algined centre in card's layout and shadow of layerlist should be lighten to give elevated view having said Imageview will use Elevation.

Comment: 'now put imageview algined centre in card's layout and shadow of layerlist should be lighten to give elevated view having said Imageview will use Elevation.' 

 <-- Can you give some code related to these lines?

Comment: Man use frame layout ..as simple as that !! just a proper alignment needed. don't have laptop can't type through keypads the whole code

Comment: it'd be much helpful if you could provide some code.