# Mask of a circle using shape?

Tags: android, android-view, shapes

i want to put a view over my android interface.
this is the idea:

[image]

I´m using a shaoe, but can not find the way to create it, I need the transparent part to be the inside of the circle and everything around it is solid.
I have searched both here and on other websites, but without success.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by shape, necessarily, but have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I want to use a listview under the circular view.

Comment: easiest way is to take image

Comment: I need to interact with the listview under the view

Comment: Use the same drawable as one of the examples there, and set it on a `FrameLayout` over the `ListView`, but without the background image. Or, subclass `ListView`, and do a simple draw in the `dispatchDraw()` method, after the `super` call. Or, depending on your minimum API, you could add a similar drawable to the `ListView`'s `ViewGroupOverlay`, or set it as its foreground attribute. Several ways to do it.