# Rounded ImageView not getting displayed properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am trying to make a rounded Image View but I am getting an improper output. I am attaching the photo

[image: Output for Rounded Image View]

These are the xml files used for this

circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

img.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_photo"/>

</layer-list>
```

The image view for this is:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/iv_person"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_person"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/img"
    android:cropToPadding="true" />
```

Comment: android:width="10dp" to android:width="1dp" and see the change

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml/41397749#41397749

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CirlcleImageView` library for rounded `ImageView`:

**compile this libray**

```
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

**Usage**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

for more information [follow this link](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Answer (score 0):

you can use external lib like

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Or use custom as

```
<shape
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="100dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

---

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  you can use 'Glide'

  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

  basically it is a network library but you can also use this for circular imageView and gif it have a very good memory management


  ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_test);

   Glide.with(this).load("your image path").asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.logo_bk).centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(img) {
        @Override
        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(this.getResources(), resource);
            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            img.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
```