# User Profile layout with Edit and Save Option

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android. I am creating a layout of the user profile. In this layout, the user can EDIT AND VIEW his profile detail. By click on edit button.

Please give me any suggestion to make this type of layout.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBTUh.jpg]

Comment: please paste your effort code here.

Comment: `I am creating a layout` then show us what you have already created.

Comment: please show us what you have attempted to do so far, because as it stands it looks like you are asking us to write the code for you

Answer (score 3):

try this it will work for you my friend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.ncrypted.dempproject.Profile">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrolView_account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="profile Details"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Please Enter User Name"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Email Address"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="password"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

for [circular image please follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172581/rounded-imageview-not-getting-displayed-properly/44172633#44172633)

Comment: thanks for this, i use android:visibility: Visible and gone for this.  'code'

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda happy to help u

Comment: @NileshRathod I aplied your solution it is working fine but in android ICS will give weird shadow effect. So better add in app:elevation="0dp" to remove the sadow. Worked for me hope this helps to someone

Comment: where is the edit upload button of circle profile image in code?

Comment: @NileshRathod: Wouldn´t it make sense to add the Java code for the XML? Just using the XML will not provide any functionality, just a layout

Comment: @DieWebagentenGmbH `Wouldn´t it make sense to add the Java code` which java code?

Comment: @NileshRathod: the code for editing the user profile, not just the XML

Comment: @DieWebagentenGmbH the above question is for how to create this type of layout not asking for the complete code for editing user's profile

Comment: @DWA .-"Please give me any suggestion to make this type of layout." xd