# how to set rectangular image into circular imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I want to fit a rectangular image in a circular view.That is image with white rounded border.I tried several methods but none of them worked properly.Can anyone help please?

Comment: this worked for me... https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105820/5617846

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but the above method didn't worked for me:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageView in circular through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml)

Comment: @RED_ But sir when i tried using circle imageview it looks perfect in the android studio design but when i run the code it displays a round without my image.

Comment: Soory!! This worked for me.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287222/5617846  ...  Run the app to see circular imageview....

Answer (score 1):

Try it out this layout you will get circular ImageView..

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/circularView"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/your_color"
            app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
             />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

To put a rectangular picture into a `circle imageView` you can use this library:
[Circle ImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Comment: i used circleimageview. but in android studio design page the image looked perfect.but when i run that code in my emulator it displays a black round without my image.

Comment: Never had this problem. If you couldn't fix it i suggest you try this library.

Comment: which library sir