# Imageview with rounded corner using kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, rounded-corners

I have created the layout with Imageview and I have set custom background with corner radius, the parent layout is cornered but the Imageview is not rounded cornered. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <solid
        android:color="@color/list_item_bg"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>

</shape>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/food_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: share your layout code.

Comment: this should help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create res/drawable/round_outline.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Set the drawable as your ImageView's background

```
android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
```

On ImageView (layout)

```
android:clipToOutline="true"
```

Comment: I have tried the above code but I got the same issue

Comment: please provider the xml layout file

Comment: I have added the code in my question.

Comment: clipToOutline is not found for imageview tag. So i followed this library:     implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'  . It works both with Java and Kotlin. Just replace your imageview with :  <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
      android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="113dp" ...etc.