# How to make Images Circular in Android?

Tags: android, xml, circleimage

I'm trying to make an image circular in the simplest way. But it just won't work.
I've also tried implementing "hdodenhof/CircleImageView" and it was of no use.
Is there any alternate reliable way of doing this?

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/spongebob"/>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

[image]

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471808/599346

Answer (score 0):

try to use `CircularImageView` library:

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/spongebob"
        app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="5"
        app:civ_shadow_color="#ff9999"/>
```

and in build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [ImageView in circular through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml) or
Use library CircularImageView created by Henning Dodenhof. You just need to write few lines of code in your xml

```xml
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```