# how can I shape Circular the selected image from gallery

Tags: java, android, xml, material-components, material-components-android

How to have a curcular ImageView. This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imgUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_border">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/studentimg"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_margin="9dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/circlepf"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my problem image sample

[image: 1]

but I want this image to show in `circular view`

Comment: You need to use CircularImageView instead of ImageView

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImageView in circular through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml)

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
With the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`** there is the new **`ShapeableImageView`**.

```
  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      ...
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circleImageView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile" />
```

with:

```
  <style name="circleImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: no,this is not my problem,my problem is when i get a image from gallery by onclicklistner then is show in full shape not in circular shape.

Comment: you can saw in my problem statement below image

Comment: @ChudamaniMeher sorry but it is not clear for me. The code posted in the answer allows to show an image as a circular shape.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this library in Github. https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout

Any layout or imageview wrapped in the MaskableFrameLayout will be cropped in the desired shape by just providing the required shape to the mask attribute of the maskLayout as shown below:

```
<com.christophesmet.android.views.maskableframelayout.MaskableFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frm_mask_animated"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    app:porterduffxfermode="DST_IN"
    app:mask="@drawable/drawable_circular"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:src="@drawable/unicorn"/>

</com.christophesmet.android.views.maskableframelayout.MaskableFrameLayout>
```

Also, you have Circleimageview library available :https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: no,this is not my problem,my problem is when i get a image from gallery by onclicklistner then is show in full shape not in circular shape.

Comment: you can saw in my problem statement below image

Comment: yeah, I understand if you want your imageview to be masked in a circular layout you could use MaskableFrameLayout. It should work fine in this scenario