# Android material lib ShapeableImageView is not showing preview with app:shapeAppearanceOverlay

Tags: android, material-components-android

There is a problem using `ShapeableImageView` material component and set `shapeAppearanceOverlay` to make it a circle image. It doesn't show up in viewport. Seems like we set the visibility to `GONE`. However, it shows perfectly on the device.

Is there any way to fix it? or since it is still in `1.2.0-alpha05` so under development or a known bug?

## Viewport Screenshot

[image]

## Device Screenshot

[image]

### Material Library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

### XML Code

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/v_blog_card_avatar"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ImageCircleTheme"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_blog_card_divider"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
```

### Style

```
<style name="ImageCircleTheme">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Comment: yeah dude, you are right. I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

`style.xml` :

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

   <!-- ShapeableImageView theme. (note that the parent matches the Base App theme) -->
    <style name="ShapeAppearance.ImageView" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

`my_layout.xml` :

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/sivAdvImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.ImageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

works with: `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03`

Comment: In `1.3.0-alpha01` the image is appearing without modifying my style but not rounded. Your code didn't work either. It shows square image.

Comment: for circle shape you can make CornerSize 50%, and check your Base application theme like,
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: Essa resposta funcionou prá mim. Vlw!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I replaced

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

with

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

Now It's working fine

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Perhaps by the time I attempt it again, Google may have fixed the issue. Thank you for your help.