# Custom CircleImageView border

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

I'm trying to build a messaging app and I want to know if it's possible to recreate the sender image and name in XML in **one shape/View**

I want to make a CircleImageView with bent shape like in this picture

[The image that i want to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnL4s.png)

The reason I want it to be one shape is that i want to be able to change the color programatically.

**PS**:Right now I managed to get close to what I want by putting a TextView behind a CircleImageView.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/22105775/10859114

Comment: i think background green is an image. Then you should code the xml in the following order.
CircleImageView -> background green -> textview.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a TextView with a drawable depending on your needs e.g. TextView with drawableLeft, drawableRight, drawableTop, drawableBottom, you can also add a drawablePadding as well as play with gravity, layout_gravity, layout_height for positioning of text vs image.

and then you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the images, you can customize the border as you want:

```
Glide.with(myFragmentOrActivity)
         .load(imageUrl)
         .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
         .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>(100,100) {

        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition)
        {
            left.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, resource, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder)
        {
            left.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, placeholder, null, null);
        }
    });
```