# cropping the top of an image on the boundary of a circle

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development and I need to create this layout.

[image]

Any suggestion on how to do the cropping of the top part of the image with the circle would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit:
This not the same as the suggested duplicate as they are cropping the entire image into a circle and I only need the top part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cropping circular area from bitmap in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android)

Comment: Please post the image you start from.

Answer (score 0):

This almost a duplicate of the linked question, so you can start from its answer to do what you want.

The relevant part to update is

```
canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
        bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
```

If you read [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)) of this method, you see that

- the first param is the x coordinate of the center of the circle
- the second param is the y coordinate of the center of the circle
- the first coordinate is the radius of the circle

In the question above, the circle is drawn from the center of the bitmap. In your case, you want the center to be at e.g. 3/4 from the top.

Try this code instead

```
canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (bitmap.getHeight() / 4) * 3,
        bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
```

and let us know.