# Drawing custom shape with dynamic content in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, android-canvas, android-shapedrawable

I want to create the screen above.

The user can update the photo from the Camera or the Gallery and Change the color of the pin. All of this changes are automatically update in the screen.

I know how to get the photo from camera or gallery, but how can I create a shape like that with the photo around? I was thinking in SVG or Canvas drawing but I really don't know how to start.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Edit custom shape]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android ?

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a good startup tutorial that introduces canvas drawing

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/introduction-to-2d-drawing-in-android.html#.VylwaPl97IU

Comment: thank you Kareem. I already know how to draw simple shapes, but I think what I need to do is more complex.