# adding color to paint path in android not working

Tags: android, arrays, view, colors, path

My app is a paint app , where the user paints on the screen . I added the color selection option so that user can select colour of the paint brush. I added undo button , so I had to add arrays to store the paint paths and color array.

Everything works fine except that the color when I select does not add to the colorarray immediately, it applies the color to the path after one path completes.

To understand clearly, take a look at my code.

```
 public class DrawingPanel extends View implements OnTouchListener {

private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint, circlePaint, outercirclePaint;
public static Bitmap defaultbitmap;
List<Integer> colorarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
public static int color=0xFFFF0000;
private  int[] mColors;



private float xleft, xright, xtop, xbottom;

public DrawingPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);



    circlePaint = new Paint();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    outercirclePaint = new Paint();
    outercirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    outercirclePaint.setColor(0x44FFF000);
    circlePaint.setColor(0xAADD5522);
    outercirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    outercirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();

    colorarray.add(color);


}

public void colorChanged(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int w = defaultbitmap.getWidth();
    int h = defaultbitmap.getHeight(); 
    Bitmap resultBmp = null;

    int widthofBitMap  = MainActivity.Width ;
    int heightofBitMap = widthofBitMap*h/w;


     resultBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(defaultbitmap, widthofBitMap, heightofBitMap, true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(resultBmp, (MainActivity.Width-widthofBitMap)/2,(MainActivity.Height-heightofBitMap)/2, mPaint);


        for( int i=0;i<paths.size();i++){

        mPaint.setColor(colorarray.get(i));
        System.out.println("colorarray size is"+colorarray.size());

        System.out.println("paths size is"+paths.size());

        canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), mPaint);

    }

}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

public void undo(){


     if (paths.size() > 0) {
     paths.remove(paths.size() - 1);

     colorarray.remove(colorarray.size()-1);

        invalidate();
     }

}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);

}

public void colorshit(){

     if(MainActivity.buttons==1)
    {
        color=0xFFFF0000;


    }
    else if(MainActivity.buttons==2)
    {

        color=0xFFFF00FF;

    }
    else if(MainActivity.buttons==3)
    {

        color=0xFF0000FF;

    }
    else if(MainActivity.buttons==4)
    {

        color=0xFF000000;

    }
    else if(MainActivity.buttons==5)
    {

        color=0xFF00FF00;

    }
    else if(MainActivity.buttons==6)
    {

        color=0xFFFFFF00;

    }

    colorarray.add(color);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        colorshit();

        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I am adding the color to color arrays in ONtouch action down, there might some other way to add color to colorarray other than in ontouch. Please suggest me some ideas.

Comment: why not use a color picker. check the second set of codes @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android/16650524#16650524

Comment: I dont think colorpicker will make any difference, as I need to add the value from color picker to the array same as I added This values in my code.

Comment: no need to add it to array. you let the use pick the color o fhis choice set the color to paint object and draw

Comment: yes but I need to add it to array if I want to undo the color, when UNDO button is clicked. If you can check my code once, you will see how i add the color for UNDO funtionality to work.

Comment: what do you mean by undo the color. Undo the drawing??