# Draw with a Canvas over an Image in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, image, canvas, bitmap

I try to draw on a Canvas, where the background is an loaded Image in Android.
It works just fine without the backgroundimage:

```
background = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.Background);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasSize,canvasSize,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
background.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Im passing that canvas to another class and draw on it. That works fine.

But when I do this:

```
background = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.Background);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher); //Just to test

canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
//or this
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));

background.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It doesn't draw over the image, so you can't see the point.
Here is the code from the other class where I use this canvas to draw:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
canvas.drawCircle( (float)sObject.getSideGforce()*mult+add, 
(float)sObject.getFrontRearGforce()*mult+add, 15*V.LOGICAL_DENSITY, dot);
```

My goal is to create a Canvas with a custom size which has an image as a background where I can draw on.
Its a Gforce Display, so the Image will be some circles with numbers and the canvas will draw a point over it so you can see how many Gs you are pulling. Like I already said it works perfectly without the background. And I dont want to redraw the background every single time I reposition the point. So the background should be static and the point should on the canvas is dynamic ( at 100hz ).
Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION:
It works with this code.

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

I just had to set the Background of my view. It stretches the image to the size of my fragment, but thats OK.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846584/android-canvas-draw-by-finger/21846585#21846585
Hope it wil help u

Comment: thanks, but that didn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` creates and immutable Bitmap, so there is why you can't change it.

You need to create a Bitmap as your working code, then use `canvas.drawBitmap()` to draw the Bitmap you want in the background. And then draw the things you want.

EDIT: Or use `setBackground()` with the background and only draw the points on the canvas.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that, but it seems that this is not the solution I'd like. Then I'd have to redraw the backgroundimage everytime. That should be static.

Comment: Then maybe use `setBackground()` on the `ImageView` with the background you want and on the canvas only drawn on it without the background

Comment: I just tested it and it works, but like I already said thats not what I wanted. I've to redraw and load the Image every single time (100 hz) although it could be static. It would work when I could delete/erase the point without affecting the image. Is there a method to do that?