# Android Signature Activity

Tags: android

I'm creating a program where the user is able to sign on screen. However, nothing is shown on the screen when the user is signing. I'm able to access the signature screen so I'm not sure if my code isn't correct since the program is not crashing

```
public class SignaturePadView extends View {

private Path path;  
private int x;
private int y;
private Canvas canvas; 
private Paint paint = new Paint();

// A "Stroke" is a collection of points drawn by the user as she puts
// her finger down, moves, and then lifts her finger up
private static class Stroke {
    private ArrayList<Point> mPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
}

// A list of all the Strokes the user has drawn with their finger
private ArrayList<Stroke> mStrokes = new ArrayList<SignaturePadView.Stroke>();



public SignaturePadView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SignaturePadView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SignaturePadView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Implement this method
    //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     super.onTouchEvent(event);
      Log.d ("motionEvent", event.toString());
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d("motionEvent", "action_up");
        this.x+=(int)event.getX();
        this.y+=(int)event.getY();
       }
      this.postInvalidate();
     return true;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO implement this
    //create path object
    super.onDraw(canvas);
//  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}

}
```

Comment: You need to check the FingerPaint Example in the docs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android

Comment: you want to create signature from ur android app?

Comment: I need to capture a signature. So the user signs a check and the signature shows up on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for capture signature:-

**java**

```
public class CaptureSignature extends Activity { 

    LinearLayout mContent;
    signature mSignature;
    Button mClear, mCancel;
    Button mGetSign;
    public static String tempDir;
    public int count = 1;
    public String current = null;
    View mView;
    public static File mypath;
    public static Bitmap mBitmap=null;
    public static Bitmap checkBitmap;
    private String uniqueId;
    private EditText yourName;
    int check_sign=0;

    public static String signaturePth;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.signature);

        tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        prepareDirectory();
        uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" + Math.random();
        current = uniqueId + ".png";
        mypath= new File(directory,current);


        mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mSignature = new signature(this, null);
        mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        mClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        mGetSign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getsign);
//        mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mView = mContent;

        yourName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourName);
        yourName.setText("sign");
        mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                check_sign=0;
                mSignature.clear();
//                mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(check_sign==1)
                {
                    boolean error = captureSignature();
                    if(!error)
                    {
                        mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        mSignature.save(mView);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        GetWaiver.flag=true;
                        b.putString("status", "done");
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtras(b);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);   
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                else if(check_sign==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(CaptureSignature.this, "Signature Required..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("status", "cancel");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);  
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean captureSignature() {

        boolean error = false;
        String errorMessage = "";


        if(yourName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            errorMessage = errorMessage + "Please enter your Name\n";
            error = true;
        }   

        if(error)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 105, 50);
            toast.show();
        }

        return error;
    }

    private String getTodaysDate() { 

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int todaysDate =     (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000) + 
        ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100) + 
        (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Log.w("DATE:",String.valueOf(todaysDate));
        return(String.valueOf(todaysDate));

    }

    private String getCurrentTime() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentTime =     (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000) + 
        (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) + 
        (c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        Log.w("TIME:",String.valueOf(currentTime));
        return(String.valueOf(currentTime));

    }


    private boolean prepareDirectory() 
    {
        try
        {
            if (makedirs()) 
            {
                return true;
            } else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean makedirs() 
    {
        File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
        if (!tempdir.exists())
            tempdir.mkdirs();

        if (tempdir.isDirectory()) 
        {
            File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) 
            {
                if (!file.delete()) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
                }
            }
        }
        return (tempdir.isDirectory());
    }

    public class signature extends View 
    {
        private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
        private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();

        private float lastTouchX;
        private float lastTouchY;
        private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

        public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        }

        public void save(View v) 
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
            Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
            if(mBitmap == null)
            {
                mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
            }
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                v.draw(canvas); 
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream); 
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, bao1);
                byte[] ba11 = bao1.toByteArray();
                String ba111 = Base64.encodeToString(ba11, 0);
                ClientDetail.m=ba111;
                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            { 
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString()); 
            } 
        }

        public void clear() 
        {
            path.reset();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            check_sign=1;
//            mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

            switch (event.getAction()) 
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) 
                {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;

            default:
                debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                return false;
            }

            invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;

            return true;
        }

        private void debug(String string){
        }

        private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) 
        {
            if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) 
            {
                dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
            } 
            else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) 
            {
                dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
            }

            if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) 
            {
                dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
            } 
            else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) 
            {
                dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
            }
        }

        private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) 
        {
            dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
            dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
        }
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dashboard_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_click"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_click"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getsign"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_click"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout> 

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/yourName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="30" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Please Sign below ..."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that's a bit too confusing for me. I'm only supposed to change onTouchEvent and onDraw