# draw a bitmap in a canvas from a class

Tags: java, android

How can I draw image from a class?
In the main I create a object with a random number, in the paint class I want to handle more stuff not just paint, because of that i think it´s best that i have a another class that draws my picture on top off the "main" background with its buttons etc..

I have read about canvas and bitmap. But cant figure out how to implement it, because I also want to change the picture i a method in this class later in my game.

Should the new class extend `ActionBarActivity` or `View`??

Can just some helpful soul give some example to guide me a little..

example of the class I create objects of:

```
public class paint {

    public Svar(int aNumber) {
        if (aNumber == 1) {
        //Paint something
                }
        if (aNumber == 2) {
                //Paint something else
        }
        if (aNumber == 3) {
                //Paint something else
        }
        if (aNumber == 4) {
                //Paint something else
        }
        if (aNumber == 5) {
                //Paint something else
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is creating a [Custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) and overriding the [onDraw](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#draw) method. After creating your custom view class you can set the content view in your Activity to that View. e.g.

```
CustomView myCustomView = new CustomView();
setContentView(myCustomView);
```

You can use the [canvas helper functions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to draw your bitmap.

Here's a good tutorial for custom views: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Here's another example emphasizing overriding the `onDraw` method:
[Draw in Canvas by finger, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android)