# Android set limits to a drawing class

Tags: android, drawing, paint, android-drawable

I fount [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android) answer here and it is almost what I need. Let's say I have a RelativeLayout inside the layout of the activity and this layout is smaller. What should I do to be able to draw only if my finger is in the inside layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by using fragments.