# Android drawing lines with arrows

Tags: android, html5-canvas, drawing

Im learining java+android, and this topic 
[Draw in Canvas by finger, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android/16650524#16650524)
helped me a lot to allow to users drawing lines. But, in my app i want to add a head of arrow to each line. It tryed using Path.lineTo to add a triangle, But the probleme is that i can't rotate it to the right direction.

Thinks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do some math. Lets say the last point of your line is A, and the last but one is B. Then we have to calculate a direction vector D as A-B. That vector should be normalized, ie divided by its own length, and then stretched to the length you want your arrow head lines to be. Using Androids `PointF` class for A,B and D, it should look something like this:

```
PointF a = <initialize with last point of your line>
PointF b = <initialize with last but one point of your line>
// difference vector
PointF d = new PointF(a.x-b.x, a.y-b.y);
// normalize
d.set(d.x / d.length(), d.y / d.length());
// stretch to, say, 10 units
d.set(10.0f * d.x, 10.0f * d.y);
```

Now the rotation part. We want to rotate by 3/4*pi, once clockwise and once counterclockwise.   We can do this using a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). For the 2-dimensional case, it is quite simple:

```
float angle = 0.75f * Math.PI;
PointF dLeft = new PointF(+d.x*Math.cos(-angle)-d.y*Math.sin(-angle),+d.x*Math.sin(-angle)+d.y*Math.cos(-angle));
PointF dRight = new PointF(+d.x*Math.cos(+angle)-d.y*Math.sin(+angle),+d.x*Math.sin(+angle)+d.y*Math.cos(+angle));
```

Note that dLeft and dRight are direction vectors. To calculate the two ending points of your arrow lines, you have to add these to A. So in pseudo-(non-java)-code you do:

```
moveTo(A);
lineTo(A+dLeft);
moveTo(A);
lineTo(A+dRight);
```

Hope this will work; good luck!