# Drawing Straight line in android using single pan tool or single finger scratches?

Tags: android

how can draw straight line using single finger or pan tool movement in android ?? when we draw one line through finger scratches, which is draw some zigzag. my exact Q? is that how to automatic straight ??
Hey ,i am using both quadTo() & lineTo() method but not exact straight line, plz improve that ANS.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dv = new DrawingView(this);
    setContentView(dv);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);  
}

 public class DrawingView extends View {

        public int width;
        public  int height;
        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;

        public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);  
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 


        }

        @Override
         protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);

        canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);

        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
             mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
        }  
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a BIG question, dude! If I were you, I'd start with a code sample [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android). That will get you finger drawing non-straight lines on the Canvas. After that you, could start thinking about how to adapt this code to your purposes. Note that there are methods for `touch_down` and `touch_up`. You could experiment with redrawing a subset of the canvas each time `touch_up` is called, replacing whatever has been drawn since the last `touch_down` with a simple line (using `canvas.lineTo()`) that links the x/y on `touch_down` with the x/y on `touch_up`.

Comment: I am agree above code statement,but i m done whole possibility but actually not found straight line as per your statement or other r&d

Comment: In that example they're using `quadTo()` to lay down the rough lines the user draws (these have control points, so they're not perfectly straight, but have curves). I'm suggesting that you could store the point at `touch_down` and an `touch_up` then, perhaps after some delay so it's obvious to the user that their line is being automagically straightened, replace the curvy lines formed by the `quadTo`s with simple straight ones formed by the `lineTo` command.

Comment: Hey,thank you for your suggestion ,but i am share updated one ,so plz resolve this prob.i am trying my best.