# Open GL Line Draw android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

[image]I am very new to Open GL. My motto is to create freehand drawing using open GL.
This I am trying to achieve through connecting vertices on Drag. My problem is as soon I tap anywhere on screen a line is drawn from center os screen to that point. I am not able to figure out why? Please help.

This is what I am doing to draw :

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    vertexData.put(toFloatarray(points));
    vertexData.clear();

    for (int i = last_size; i < points.size(); i++) {

        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, i , 2);
        last_size = points.size();

    }

}
```

I know for loop is not the best way and this is the issue but I am not able to get over it.

EDIT:

This is how I am adding points to array

```
public void handleTouchDrag(float normalizedX, float normalizedY) {
    points.add(normalizedX);
    points.add(normalizedY);

}
```

where :

```
final float normalizedX = (event.getX() / (float) v.getWidth()) * 2 - 1;
final float normalizedY = -((event.getY() / (float) v.getHeight()) * 2 - 1);
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper thanks but i need to do it in open gl not canvas

Comment: Can you show the code on how you are inserting points to the array.

Comment: @codetiger : Please see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

You are feeding the function with only one vertex and requesting to draw a line segment, and OpenGL decides to consider the second point to be origin.

You can use

```
 glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, points.size());
```

And this will draw lines to previous point.

Comment: Better remove the for loop and try this glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, points.size()); I've also edited my code in the answer.

Comment: I have uploaded screenshot of result that I am getting both ways, with or without For loop..I only dragged and drew the bottom line but the center one connected the bottom one is drawing on its own. Please help

Comment: If you are drawing GL_LINES, you are suppose to give 2 vertices (x1, y1, x2, y2). and GL_LINE_STRIP will drawling from previous vertex.