# How to get a snapshot of the view?

Tags: android, view, screenshot

I am currently using a View to trace the users fingers and draw lines depending on the color picked. I have set the background image using `setBackGround()` but I would now like to get the background + what the user user drawn into a variable. There exists getBackGround and getForeGround, not not both. How do I achieve this? I do not want to store the image locally on the persons phone.

The code used to achieve the tracing was used from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android) and the `setBackground` was achieved by,

```
  dv = new DrawingView(this);
  dv.setBackground(imageview.getDrawable());
```

Where the imageview was defined and has data in it before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass view(name of the view), Where a view is like a relativeLayout

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    view.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();

    imageView.setImageBitmap(returnedBitmap);
```