# Crop an image to a fixed size

Tags: android, android-image

I'm capturing an image with the camera, then I'm saving it into a Bitmap. I'm looking forward to center-crop that image, to 600x600px.

Something like this I've found:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909144/1943607

However, I can't find out how can I set a fixed with & height.

I'm soo bad at drawing images and canvas. It seems to be so abstract for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)</kbd> is exactly what you need.

```
// Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source bitmap.
static Bitmap createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

I don't really know if (0,0) is top-left or center, but I believe it's top-left.

```
* (0,0)

*~~~~~~+===========+
'      '           |
'      ' 200       |
'      '           |
+~~~~~~+           | 400
|  100             |
|                  |
|                  |
+==================+
        300
```

If it's indeed the center then:

```
x should be width /2
y    >>     height/2
```

Otherwise if it's top left:

```
x should be width /2 - cropWidth/2
y    >>     height/2 - cropHeight/2
```

On both occasions would look like this.

```
* (150,200)

+==================+
|                  |
|     +~~~~~~+     |
|     '      '     |
|     '  *   '200  | 400
|     '      '     |
|     +~~~~~~+     |
|       100        |
+==================+
        300
```

Comment: got something like `newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap, x, y, 500, 500);`. As you can see, x and y are missing. I'm not sure about how to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

600x600px

```
if(srcBmp.getWidth()>600 && srcBmp.getHeight()>600) 
    dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp, 
         srcBmp.getWidth()/2 - 600/2,
         srcBmp.getHeight()/2 - 600/2,
         600,
         600);
```

I change the code from the link you gave, hope this works.