# Fit image to screen width in viewpager in landscape mode in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have a `VerticalViewPager` and I have some images in it. When I rotate my device in landscape mode my `ImageView` doesn't scale to width of my screen. It fits the height if image instead. I used `AspectRatioImageView`. It fits the width but `VerticalViewPager` doesn't scroll down.
Thank you.

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<HackyViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vvp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    >
</HackyViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is `rowitemview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fff" >
    <AspectRatioImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/m4_3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my `instaniateItem` of my `ImagePageAdapter` that extends `PagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
        Context context = MainActivity.this;

        container.requestLayout();
          AspectRatioImageView imageView = new     AspectRatioImageView(context);
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m4_3));


          mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
          mAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(new OnMatrixChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {
                if((int)rect.width()>_width)
                    viewPager.setLocked(true);
                else
                    viewPager.setLocked(false);
            }
        });
```

P.S : The issue is with `viewPager` height. When I scroll down the image it just goes to the other page instead of scrolling the scaled image.

Comment: please add your code and you layout .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's what you need.**

This is a good solution I found out.

[Android Crop Center of Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908604/android-crop-center-of-bitmap)

This allows to set the height and your width according to your orientation.

To change the image's scale to full screen, you generally use center crop like this:

```
yourImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Hope this information was useful..:)

Comment: I don't have problem with image scale. I use `AspectRatioImageView` and it works fine. The problem is that `ViewPager` doesn't scale it's height to the container.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue of unwanted image margins on the left and right.

Answer (score -1):

Use  `android:scalType = "fitxy"` in activity code like this `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`