# How to center-crop layout background programatically

Tags: android

I'm setting the background of a layout programmatically. How do I center-crop the background?

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myUri);
BitmapDrawable dw = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(dw);
```

**edit**

I am looking for the Java equivalent of `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: post full code please

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905248/how-to-centercrop-an-image-programatically-by-maintaining-aspect-ratio-like-cent

Comment: @piotrek1543 I see. So there's no API for it. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this would be useful: https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112715/how-to-crop-bitmap-center-like-imageview)

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

    // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
    // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger 
    // of these two.
    float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
    float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
    float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

    // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
    float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
    float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

    // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
    // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
    float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
    float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

    // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
    // be
    RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

    // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
    // scaled bitmap onto it.
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not directly achievable with View backgrounds.

But you have the option to use an ImageView instead and place it behind your actual View using a FrameLayout to 'simulate' a backround. Then you can use `centerCrop` option:

```
<FrameLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <!-- your actual View here -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Really? I can't use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` for a layout?

Comment: @the_prole `scaleType` is only available for ImageViews.

Comment: I tried adding a background to an image view in Java with XML attirbute `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` but I don't see the cropping effect. I don't think I can combine Java and XML in this way.