# Horizontal crop of ImageView using a SeekBar (Android)

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I want to control the horizontal crop of an `ImageView` using a `SeekBar`, like presented in this photo:

[image: Crop controlled by a Seekbar]

This is my code for the `progressChanged` event:

```
    cropSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            float tuning = (float) progress/seekBar.getMax();

            if (tuning == 0) {
                return;
            }

            int width = (int)(tuning * originalPhotoBitmap.getWidth());
            int height = originalPhotoBitmap.getHeight();

            modifiedPhotoBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalPhotoBitmap, 0, 0, width, height);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(modifiedPhotoBitmap);
        }
    });
```

The new width is calculated correctly (I checked the value in logcat), but when I set the imageView's bitmap with `setImageBitmap` it appears that the ScaleType `FIT_CENTER` isn't working anymore...

What I'm actually getting with my code is this:

Progress value: 100

[image: Progress value is 100]

Progress value: 50

[image: Progress value is 50]

Progress value: 25

[image: Progress value is 25]

As you can see, it is not the desired behavior...

**My questions are two:**

1. What scale type should I use in the ImageView?
2. Is my new bitmap defined correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1- What scale type should I use in the ImageView?
Not shure if i understood correctly but if you want to set the ImageView centralized you should use Gravity attribute.

2- Is my new bitmap defined correctly?
I beleve the awnser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908604/android-crop-center-of-bitmap) by Lumis should help you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this isn't making new bitmaps-  in fact that's the worst way to do it.  The easiest way is to alter the width of the image view via its layout params

Comment: so the imageView width will not alter its content width(the actual photo)? the imageView width is, then, the container width?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int progress) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() * progress / 100, bitmap.getHeight(), paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Use like this:

```
int progress = 70;
imageView.setImageBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(originalPhotoBitmap, progress));
```

Comment: I keep my ImageView with FIT_CENTER?

Comment: oh.. I posted sample to github https://github.com/nshmura/TestCrop . If this dose not works in your environment, Could you tell me your enviroment (Android OS version and you device) ?