# bitmap equivalent centerCrop

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am coding a splashscreen.
My app must work with tablet and phones so my splashcreen is a landscape.
On phones, the image's ratio is changed. How can I crop the left and right border while centering the image ?

This is my code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background" 
                android:gravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

Comment: I think you need to create a new bitmap as center crop unless you use ImageView with src tag . Look into [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908604/android-crop-center-of-bitmap).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the selector:

```
<item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
```