# How to crop the screenshot please?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, screenshot, crop

Hello i have a code to take a screenshot then share it and its work very well
But i want to crop this screenshot from the both top and bottom .
I hope to help me because i am new in coding .
This is the code that i use it :

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
        saveBitmap(bitmap);
        shareIt();
    }


    public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }

    private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png"); ////File imagePath
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void shareIt() {
        Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
});


    displayResults();

}
```

Comment: you have to search before asking. I don't believe you did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Crop Center of Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908604/android-crop-center-of-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library, you can implement this [library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). And follow this code

From ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/> <!-- optional (needed if default theme has no action bar) -->
```

**To start CropImageActivity**

```
// start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping 
activity
CropImage.activity()
         .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
         .start(this);

// start cropping activity for pre-acquired image saved on the device
CropImage.activity(imageUri)
         .start(this);

// for fragment (DO NOT use `getActivity()`)
CropImage.activity()
         .start(getContext(), this);
```

**Override onActivityResult**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
          Exception error = result.getError();
        }
      }
    }
```