# Crop bitmap image in rectangular

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I want to crop an image without using any library.

I am taking reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909144 and try to change the value but can't figure out the solution

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtil.getBitmap(path);

                    Log.d(TAG,"bitmap  width : "+bitmap.getWidth()+"  height:  "+bitmap.getHeight());

                    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()){
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Height Greater",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG,"Greater : Height");
                        textView.setText("Height Greater");
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                bitmap,
                                bitmap.getWidth()/2 - bitmap.getHeight()/2,
                                0,
                                bitmap.getHeight(),
                                bitmap.getHeight()
                        );

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Width Greater",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG,"Greater : Width");
                        textView.setText("Width Greater");
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                bitmap,
                                0,
                                bitmap.getHeight()/2 - bitmap.getWidth()/2,
                                bitmap.getWidth(),
                                bitmap.getWidth()
                        );
                    }
```

I want a crop bitmap image within the rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For efficiently creating bitmaps, try this

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

    /**
     * 
     * ImageScalingUtils responsible for compressing the bitmap efficiently
     */
    object ImageScalingUtils {

        /**
         * Utility function for decoding an image resource. The decoded bitmap will
         * be optimized for further scaling to the requested destination dimensions
         * and scaling logic.
         *
         * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
         * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
         * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
         * @return Decoded bitmap
         */


        fun decodeBitmap(bm: Bitmap, dstWidth: Int, dstHeight: Int,
                         scalingLogic: ScalingLogic): Bitmap {
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
            val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size, options)
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
            options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                    dstHeight, scalingLogic)
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size, options)
        }

        /**
         * ScalingLogic defines how scaling should be carried out if source and
         * destination image has different aspect ratio.
         *
         * CROP: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure that at least
         * one of the two dimensions fit inside the requested destination area.
         * Parts of the source image will be cropped to realize this.
         *
         * FIT: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure both
         * dimensions fit inside the requested destination area. The resulting
         * destination dimensions might be adjusted to a smaller size than
         * requested.
         */
        enum class ScalingLogic {
            CROP, FIT
        }

        /**
         * Calculate optimal down-sampling factor given the dimensions of a source
         * image, the dimensions of a destination area and a scaling logic.
         *
         * @param srcWidth Width of source image
         * @param srcHeight Height of source image
         * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
         * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
         * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
         * @return Optimal down scaling sample size for decoding
         */
        private fun calculateSampleSize(srcWidth: Int, srcHeight: Int, dstWidth: Int, dstHeight: Int,
                                        scalingLogic: ScalingLogic): Int {
            if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
                val srcAspect = srcWidth.toFloat() / srcHeight.toFloat()
                val dstAspect = dstWidth.toFloat() / dstHeight.toFloat()

                return if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                    srcWidth / dstWidth
                } else {
                    srcHeight / dstHeight
                }
            } else {
                val srcAspect = srcWidth.toFloat() / srcHeight.toFloat()
                val dstAspect = dstWidth.toFloat() / dstHeight.toFloat()

                return if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                    srcHeight / dstHeight
                } else {
                    srcWidth / dstWidth
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Scaled Picture class to scale your picture

```
 import android.content.ContentResolver
    import android.graphics.Bitmap
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
    import android.graphics.Matrix
    import android.graphics.RectF
    import android.net.Uri
    import androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException
    import java.io.IOException
    import java.io.InvalidObjectException

    /**
     *
     * ScaledPicture responsible for compressing the bitmap efficiently
     */
    class ScaledPicture(private var uri: Uri?, private var resolver: ContentResolver) {
        private var path: String? = null
        private var orientation: Matrix? = null
        private var storedHeight: Int = 0
        private var storedWidth: Int = 0

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        private fun getInformation(): Boolean {
            /*if (getInformationFromMediaDatabase())
                return true;*/
            return getInformationFromFileSystem()
        }

        /* Support for file managers and dropbox */
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        private fun getInformationFromFileSystem(): Boolean {
            path = uri?.path
            if (path == null)
                return false
            val exif = ExifInterface(path.toString())
            val orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
            this.orientation = Matrix()
            when (orientation) {
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL -> {
                }
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL -> this.orientation?.setScale(-1f, 1f)
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> this.orientation?.setRotate(180f)
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL -> this.orientation?.setScale(1f, -1f)
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE -> {
                    this.orientation?.setRotate(90f)
                    this.orientation?.postScale(-1f, 1f)
                }
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> this.orientation?.setRotate(90f)
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE -> {
                    this.orientation?.setRotate(-90f)
                    this.orientation?.postScale(-1f, 1f)
                }
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> this.orientation?.setRotate(-90f)
            }/* Identity matrix */
            return true
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        private fun getStoredDimensions(): Boolean {
            val input = resolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resolver.openInputStream(uri), null, options)
            /* The input stream could be reset instead of closed and reopened if it were possible
               to reliably wrap the input stream on a buffered stream, but it's not possible because
               decodeStream() places an upper read limit of 1024 bytes for a reset to be made (it calls
               mark(1024) on the stream). */

            input?.close()
            if (options.outHeight <= 0 || options.outWidth <= 0)
                return false
            storedHeight = options.outHeight
            storedWidth = options.outWidth
            return true
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        fun getBitmap(reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Bitmap {
            val heightWidth = 1000
            if (!getInformation())
                throw FileNotFoundException()
            if (!getStoredDimensions())
                throw InvalidObjectException(null)
            val rect = RectF(0f, 0f, storedWidth.toFloat(), storedHeight.toFloat())
            orientation?.mapRect(rect)
            var width = rect.width().toInt()
            var height = rect.height().toInt()
            var subSample = 1
            while (width > heightWidth || height > heightWidth) {
                width /= 2
                height /= 2
                subSample *= 2
            }
            if (width == 0 || height == 0)
                throw InvalidObjectException(null)
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inSampleSize = subSample
            val subSampled = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resolver.openInputStream(uri), null, options)
            val picture: Bitmap
            if (orientation?.isIdentity == false) {
                picture = Bitmap.createBitmap(subSampled, 0, 0, options.outWidth, options.outHeight,
                        orientation, false)
                subSampled.recycle()
            } else

                picture = subSampled

            return ImageScalingUtils.decodeBitmap(picture, reqWidth, reqHeight, ImageScalingUtils.ScalingLogic.CROP)
        }

    }
```

Copy the above classes to your project, and use it like this

```
var bitmap = ScaledPicture(mSelectedUri, contentResolver).getBitmap(800, 800)
```

Pass your desired height and width

Comment: Thanks for response, i tried you solution but didn't work, image is not getting cropped.

Comment: what issue you are facing

Comment: actually my  xml frame width = 260 and height =400 and image side  width = 1080  height = 1920

Comment: the solution you provided return the bitmap as it is

Comment: Did the bit `Scaled()` picture class returned you is with the actual image with its original size?

Comment: I m getting bitmap with compress size but its not get cropped.
Example
before bitmap  width : 1080  height:  1920
after crop bitmap  width : 540  height:  960

Comment: I got your problem, but with your requirement, how could you specify, which 800x900 should crop from the 1920x1080  size image

Comment: yes thats the problem, actually i placed frame layout inside relative layout with alignparentcenter true,and framelayout got width as 260 and height as 400, so whatever will be image size, the center part of image will get cropped, thats what i m looking for.. betwwen thanks for you efforts and response..