# How to get degree of rotation of image

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-gallery

I'm getting an image from gallery and display it in an imageView. Sometimes, image displays 90 degrees CCW.

So, my question is:
1- is it possible to get angle of rotation of image?
2- is it possible to get angle by a face detection library? if yes, which library you suggest?

any recommendation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to check the Exiforientation value in your image file. That is the only relaible solution

Comment: Thanks man. I saw this before but not all images has this argument. That's why I'm thinking to a face detection solution.

Comment: then you have to detect the orientation of face too and that could also not be correct. what if there is no face to detect? consider two person one hanging by a fence upside down and another standing how are you going to solve this situation. Just add a rotate button. Thats what I did in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found a solution that I share it with you.

```
public class ImageCorrection extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 100;

    private ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_face_detection);

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Image Uri: " + imageUri.toString());

                    try {
                        Bitmap myImg = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        if(myImg == null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Image bitmap is null...");
                            return;
                        }

                        Cursor cur;
                        String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                            cur = managedQuery(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
                        else
                            cur = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);

                        int orientation = -1;
                        if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                            orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
                            Log.d(TAG, "Image Orientation: " + orientation);
                        }

                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.reset();
                        matrix.postRotate(orientation);

                        Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        imageButton.setImageBitmap(rotated);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```